# Codeigntier extend Email library ci 3.0.4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have trying to override the email library by doing the following steps:

1. Create file core/MY_Email.php
2. In file add code below

   ```
   <?php
   class MY_Email extends CI_Email {

       public function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
       }
   ?>
   ```
3. Load library is normal

   ```
       $this->load->library('email');
   ```

I put a die in the top of my class and it appears to not even be included and just uses the regular system email class. I need to extend it to override _smtp_connect(). I have done this with other classes.

I am using CI 3.0.4. I have tried to trace through the loader class; but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put MY_Email.php in application/libraries

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the file in application/libraries NOT application/core

Comment: Is this answer or comment

Answer (score 0):

```php
$this->load->library('email');
```

Create a new file called `MY_Email.php` and put it in `application/libraries/`