# CodeIgniter - Load system library from my library not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to make my library to send email.
In my controller I set up as:

```
$this->load->library('MY_Email'); // My library has been loaded
```

File `MY_Email.php`

```
class MY_Email {
    public $ci;
    public $config;
    public $email;

    public function __construct () {
        $ci = &get_instance();
        $ci->load->config('email');
        $this->config = array(
            'protocol'     => $ci->config->item('email_protocol'),
            'smtp_host'    => $ci->config->item('email_smtp_host'),
            'smtp_port'    => $ci->config->item('email_smtp_port'),
            'smtp_timeout' => $ci->config->item('email_smtp_timeout'),
            'smtp_user'    => $ci->config->item('email_smtp_user'),
            'smtp_pass'    => $ci->config->item('email_smtp_pass'),
            'charset'      => $ci->config->item('email_charset'),
            'mailtype'     => $ci->config->item('email_mailtype'),
            'validation'   => $ci->config->item('email_validation')
        );

        $ci->load->library('email', $this->config);

        /*This line print `Undefined property: Controller::$email` and result is NULL*/
        var_dump($ci->email); die;
    }
}
```

What is my wrong?
Thanks for any helps

Comment: Are you trying to extend the library? Because that what MY_Email is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777413/codeigntier-extend-email-library-ci-3-0-4

Comment: Its print `Class 'CI_Email' not found`

Comment: Try `application/libraries/MY_Email.php` and `class  MY_Email extends CI_Email {}` because you are extending I would not think you need this `$ci->load->library('email', $this->config);` If you are not trying to extend it then rename file and class https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html?highlight=create%20libraries

Comment: Yes bro I tried. I removed all `$ci`, extends `CI_Email`. Its return `Class 'CI_Email' not found ... on line 2`